# Python - Typings for http request call results

Tags: python, python-typing

I'm interested in writing clean, readable and maintainable code. Some time we have to interact with external API. For example httpbin.org. For me it would be a good idea to somehow fix request call result structure in code. For example httpbin.org/get returns:

```
{
  "args": {},
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "ru,en;q=0.9",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "Referer": "https://httpbin.org/",
    "Sec-Ch-Ua": "\" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"102\", \"Yandex\";v=\"22\"",
    "Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile": "?0",
    "Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform": "\"macOS\"",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.167 YaBrowser/22.7.5.1018 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-456c9715-53b4jhdsjhbjdh3dskjea0"
  },
  "origin": "134.51.34.46",
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/get"
}
```

Now I see the way to convert the json into NamedTuple/dataclass/Pydantic.

I wonder to know if there is some common approaches or maybe ready solutions/libs or so for this? Also I need this for accessing through dot.

Comment: What information do you actually need from this response? It's bad for maintainability to add dependencies that you don't need. Most of it actually looks fairly standard and are covered by `requests.Response`.

Comment: For modeling JSON data returned from REST calls, I like using the Pydantic library. It allows you to convert JSON blobs into fully typed python objects easily.

Comment: I personally use dataclass-wizard as its a bit more lightweight than pydantic (also disclaimer: i am the creator). Using `wiz` cli tool, it can generate class schema from json easily and then after that it is straightforward to load json data to a new class object.

Comment: `dataclass` (and `dataclassy`) allows you to add some validation manually, `pydantic` - to reuse popular validations, `namedtuple` - less appropriate hear, `typing.TypedDict` - to type the actual dictionary keys (no runtime checking, only typecheckers), [`marshmallow`](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is designed for (de)serialization, [`voluptuous`](https://pypi.org/project/voluptuous/) is designed specifically for your use case but may look too simple or not very convenient for somebody, [`attrs`](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs) are good too... It's opinion-based.